# script tags in html

Tags: asp.net, tags

I'm having difficulties google what's the difference between the following script tags:

```
<%# ... %> 

<% = ... %>

<% ... %>
```

Can someone help?

Comment: There is nothing like <%#. <%= is the expression and <% is the scriptlet, This is JSP Related stuff. You gave wrong tags(html, JS). If u don't know the basic stuff, try reading from the beginning.

Comment: @Alex R., why do you think it's Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These tags also may be ASP.NET tags.

Here are links with the information about each tag:

`<%# ... %>` [Data-Binding Expression Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx.aspx)

`<%= ... %>` [Displaying from ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

`<% ... %>`  [Embedded Code Blocks in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Although my line is: <%# String.Format("{0:N2} pending", Container.DataItem["Balance"]) %>

          No 'Eval' or 'Bind'

Comment: @user311130, changed link for <%# ... %>. The right one for you is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i don't know about the 1st one

but 2 and 3 was the jsp tag,

2 one is the expression tag like when you want to get value from jsp variable then you can use this tag

for e.g.

```
String arg = "Pratik"
```

now you want use this in jsp page anywhere

```
Hello <%= name %> ////// it will print on web page as Hello Pratik
```

the 3rd one is the script tag
when you want write block of jsp,java code you can write within this tag

for ex.

```
<%
   String name="";
   name = "abc";
   out.println(name);
 %>
```